# Dynamically changing the type of a Shield UI JavaScript chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am using a Shield UI JavaScript chart. The chart displays data for users and its type depends on a selectionn users can make. let's say a dropdown, which determines the chart type. Everything works fine, however i was curious whether it is possible to just change the series type and not to recreate the chart, using the destroy() method.
I did some research, but could't find anything in the documentation (https://shieldui.com/documentation) regarding this matter...

Any ideas and comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to just change the type of the chart without recreating (re-rendering) it. Besides even if it were possible, it wouldn't be of any use, since all of the points will need to be re-drawn, so in terms of efficiency you won't gain any.